# Id serialization does not update when I create objects using shell in Django PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a module called **shell_functions** where I have the following function:

```
def add_areas():
    for data in some_data:
        Area.objects.create(id=data['id'], name=data['name'])
```

I run this function from the shell to create objects. After this, I tried creating an Area from the admin panel. However, this time I get an integrity error saying the Area with the id=1 already exists. Obviously, the id serialization counter did not update itself as I explicitly put in the id in the shell function. How to solve this issue? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Normally you never pass ids explicitly. The database should "dispatch" ids. By specifying one explicitly, you will indeed for some databases make the sequence "corrupt".

Comment: Its for a system migration, so ids need to be explicitly set unfortunately.

Comment: I know that MySQL normally when you "reboot" the database, sets the id dispatcher to the maximum assigned id. For PostgreSQL, I'm not sure. You can probably alter the sequence manually, for example with an SQL query (or with certain frontends).